How to get WebRTC metrics?
Is there any other way to get WebRTC metrics not using web page (browser_name)://webrtc-internals/?
I've been trying to get WebRTC metrics by parsing the web page itself but it won't work out for my needs, i need a less resources consuming approach (will take a look at any other option)
I also tried to get them from JS but i can only create a new RTCPeerConnection() that doesn't have the metrics for the existing ones

Metrics like what exactly?

@deceze like video bitrate
